# Unusual firewire 800 port

Tags: macbook-pro, firewire

I have a new Macbook Pro 13 (I think its the 2011 issue) which has a firewire 800 port with an unusual form factor.  It's different to the FW800 port on my older macbook pro 17.

Can anyone tell me the name of that form factor so I can find a adapter or cables?

Comment: Do you see a lightning bolt next to the port on your machine? If so, that's a Thunderbolt port: http://bit.ly/feuNdM .

Comment: Also, you can enter your serial number in after the # to get the exact model number for your Mac. http://support.apple.com/manuals/#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the exact same FW800 / 9 pin connector as most recent macs. The unibody frame has the port set a slight bit deeper on the unibody macs than was common on the non-unibody macs.

Here is the diagram from the MacBook Pro 13 inch (Mid 2010) and the only difference in the newer MacBook Pro is the substitution of an identically sized Thunderbolt port instead of the DisplayPort socket.

[image]